# Django, Python X value in List of Dicts/Queryset

Tags: python, django

i get all codes i have,

```
codes_in_db = DistribuidorCodes.objects.all().values('code')

#[{'code': u'pelicano815'}, {'code': u'perro10189'}...]
```

what i want to do is to make a new list

```
myList = list()
code = generate_code()
if code not in codes_in_db:
    myList.append(code)
```

this code doesnt work, what am i missing.. i know should be a way to get the value of code... but im having a hard time, and i couldnt find a question that does exactly this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a list with code's value only. You could try this:

```
DistribuidorCodes.objects.all().values_list('code', flat=True)
```

That should return this:

```
[u'pelicano815', u'perro10189', ...]
```